# Raspberry Pi Zero and USB camera Issue

Tags: usb, camera

I have a video streaming application which works well on the Raspberry Pi 2. I am trying to switch out the Pi 2 and move everything to a Pi Zero.

When I connect the USB camera to the Pi Zero directly the camera works fine. If I connect the camera and a WiFi adapter to the Pi using a hub, the camera doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get everything working?

I am using a hub with its own power source.

Comment: I can't understand your question. Can you try rephrasing it?

Comment: I am using Raspberry pi 2 and I have an application for real time video streaming. I want to replace Pi2 with Raspberry pi Zero, but as you it has just only one OTG USB port. So, I can not use camera with the wireless keyboard in the same time. When I add the USB hub as a solution, everything works fine except the camera. with the USB hub, I can use wireless keyboard, WiFi, Bluetooth, ect....

Comment: So when you connect the camera to the Pi Zero using a hub (which presumably also has a WiFi adapter plugged into it), the camera no longer works?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: @Sam4mNewcastle: Please edit the actual question so it makes more sense, rather than adding a bunch of comments to clarify.

Comment: How much current do the WiFi adapter and your camera draw, and how much current do you supply to your Pi Zero? Is the USB hub powered?

Comment: the USB was powered externally. I am not about the power consumption for WiFi and Camera. But when I start using them with the Pi A, 2B there was no problem.

Comment: Have a look at `lsusb` and see if the camera is shown.  If it isn't, you could try the [trick that worked for me here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/50975/5538) regarding stuff connected to a hub on the pi.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that the webcam doesn't get enough power via the hub. You could try a powered USB hub.

Comment: Comments on the question indicate it is powered externally (I've edited that into the question itself now).

Answer (score -1):

Try again with only the camera connected to the USB hub i.e. no keyboard or anything else. If it works then it's a power issue with the hub.