# External powered HDD not listed after boot

Tags: boot, hard-drive, usb-hub, hub

I have an hub for HDDs where I have two of them (WD purple 2TB).

If the Raspberry is ON and I switch on also the hub, the two HDDs are recognized by the Pi as sda and sdb (listed with sudo fdisk -l).

While if the Raspberry is switched off and the hub is switched on and I turn on the Raspberry, the two HDDs are not recognized (so not listed too).

In some discussions I read about adding to /boot/cmdline.txt rootdelay=5. I tried it but, nothing changed, so I tried also 10, 15, 150. But as before, it didn't solved the issue.

What could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something akin to what [worked here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/50976/5538) with regard to an OTG hub on a Pi Zero.

However, the situation is a little different on the other models, where the onboard hub has two entries in `/sys` (possibly due to the ethernet controller which is part of the USB controller, but more likely due to the way the hub is configured for use as a USB master -- doesn't matter for our purposes).

You need to go into `/sys/bus/usb/devices`, where there is set of symlinked directories and files; we are interested in the directories which have a format such as `1-1:1.0`, keeping in mind that that and `1-0:1.0` are the onboard hub.  There is a bit of an [explanation of how to do that here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265736/25985), although that may not be easy to follow partially because of how the numbering scheme output from `lsusb -t` works.  However, that command should clearly indicate the hub itself as a brand identifier should be included.  Most likely, the directory you are looking for is `2-0:1.0`.

Inside there is another set of [symlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), one of which is `driver`.  Use `readlink driver` to see what that points to; if it ends in `bus/usb/drivers/hub` you've found it *[but see also comments at bottom]*.

Now go to `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/hub` (you can use the `driver` symlink, e.g., `cd driver`); there will be symlinked directories there including `2-0:1.0` (if that's the hub).  There should also be two file nodes, `bind` and `unbind`.  As per the answer linked in the first question, from inside that directory, try:

```
echo "2-0:1.0" > unbind
```

Then

```
echo "2-0:1.0" > bind
```

You have to do this as root, e.g., by using `su`; you cannot use `sudo` because they use redirection (`>`), but you could put them in a script with a brief `sleep`, as per the first linked answer, and use `sudo` with that.

*Beware when you do this everything on the hub will be disconnected, so if that includes a wifi adapter and you are logging in remotely, you will have to attach that directly to the pi first instead.*  It doesn't matter about the pi itself because the power from the hub won't be affected.

Now try just plain `lsusb`.  It and `fdisk -l` should show the drives.

If that works, you can use the same strategy from the first linked answer with `/etc/rc.local` to ensure when the pi boots up, the drives should be found.  That file is run root by the [init system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), but you can run it yourself to similar effect (in this case, anyway) with `sudo`.

Comment: Great, this is the solution. There's just something different, infact I saw from lsusb -t that the driver of my HDDs' hub, when connected after switched off and on again, is usb-storage so I unbinded and binded from /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage

Comment: I've noted that for posterity ;) Plugging and unplugging the data link to the hub is probably an easy way to find the directory if you are looking in `/sys/bus/usb/devices` with a file browser too.