# External Powered USB drive doesnt work if connected at boot

Tags: usb, boot-issues, hard-drive

If I plug in my external hard drives they work fine, but if I have them plugged in at boot they do not show up.

They are external hard disk caddies that I have put hard drives in.

The same happens if I try one at a time.

`lsblk`only shows the mmc devices of the pi

`ls /dev` doesn't show any "sdX" drives

adding `dwc_otg.speed=1` `/boot/cmdline.txt` didnt help

dmesg doesn't seem to show them, but there are a few items with usb in the name output below, as I don't understand it all fully.

```
[    0.152200] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.152302] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.152416] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.359499] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    0.811008] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    0.817755] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.824635] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: irq 62, io mem 0x00000000
[    0.844835] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.851554] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.858263] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    0.864853] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.41-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    0.871561] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 3f980000.usb
[    0.893471] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    0.974922] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    0.981765] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.310596] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    1.590869] usb 1-1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[    1.598404] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514
[    1.605679] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.940617] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    2.080917] usb 1-1.1: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[    2.081210] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[    2.081219] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.205862] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:26:84:b0
[    2.540652] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    3.080735] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[    3.630714] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[    4.180723] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[    4.455916] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
```

Comment: the usb adapters in question register as `JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp.`

Comment: `lsusb` also does not show the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would hardly call it perfect I have found a solution, I think.

[This](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51707/external-powered-hdd-not-listed-after-boot) post and the related link within gave me the right direction, but it still was not working. As a last ditch I have added in a usb hub as that allows me to effectively switch the hard drives on and off at each boot time.

Hope this can help someone out there, I do not know the root cause. I wish I did so I could submit a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also boot from hard drives with my PI's but have found that they need to be running independantly before switching on the PI. Its all about access time!