# Pi Zero USB Issues

Tags: usb, power

Pi Zero with following connections:

1. HDMI to monitor
2. USB1 to IKEA USB Power Socket (2400mA)
3. USB2 to USB Hub:

   - USB adaptor for wireless keyboard and mouse
   - USB WiFi adaptor (Cisco LinkSys)

This configuration works... sometimes but, in general, when I boot I have no keyboard mouse. When I unplug the hub and connect the keyboard/mouse adaptor I have keyboard and mouse. When I then re-connect the hub and everything it works... sometimes.

I suspect a power issue - but surely that would crash the Pi?

Can I connect USB power to one of the free hub ports to boost things without breaking things?

Comment: I had a similar problem: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/50975/5538

Comment: I don't think it's a power issue(unless your power socket is broken)... The pi zero barely uses any power, and 2400mA is plenty for a pi zero, a mouse, keyboard, and usb adapter...(at least it _should_ be...)

Comment: Just used a different USB hub and we're good.