# Raspberry Pi USB hub can't connect keyboard and mouse at same time

Tags: usb, pi-zero, keyboard, mouse, usb-hub

I bought a cheap USB hub for a Raspberry Pi Zero:
[USB hub from AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/HIPERDEAL-New-White-Micro-USB-To-4-Port-OTG-Hub-For-Raspberry-Zero-Hot-18Mar24-Drop/32861039697.html)

The problem is that I can't plug in the keyboard and mouse at the same time.
Just one device is working and at one specific usb port on the hub.

I know that it's cheap from AliExpress but it's made for a RPi Zero.
Interestingly, it works perfectly with my Android phone.

Do you have any ideas or can you recommend any USB hubs, which are cheap and work with a RPi?

Comment: This is not exactly the same problem, but you could try the solution (unbind and rebind the driver): https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/50975/5538 It may also be a power problem; although it should probably be able to handle a keyboard and mouse, I think the Zero is not up to snuff generally WRT available USB power.

Comment: It would be good if you could refrain from using cuss words

Answer (score 1):

I’ve tried plugging in usb hubs and had a similar issue. My first way is to use a beefy power adapter like the apple iPad charging brick 10+watts of power. If that doesn’t work than send a picture of inside the hub and find out if its circuit is in parallel or series.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Note that we tend to [*skip signature, taglines, or greetings*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) here.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this one http://www.uugear.com/product/zero4u/
It works perfectly fine with raspberry pi zero 1.3/W. Initially even I was
in doubt of buying this since there are many problems in getting the connection
of raspberry pi with hub. You can go with this one as it is officially tested
hub.